# how to connect with cassandra installed of different server using node js

Tags: node.js, cassandra

i am connecting to cassandra database using node js. the present db is working on the same server. But now we have new server for cassandra. now i am not getting what changes are required to connect to cassandra.
current code:

var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['localhost'], keyspace: 'ipop' });

Answer (score 2):

Instead of localhost you should use the ip of the new cassandra server. Also, if you Cassandra is using some other port for listening to client connection instead of the default 9042 you should use the option protocolOptions.port

Comment: i tried that but it is not able to connect to that ip. i am not sure why is that. I have checked possible solution. many palces i have found we need to make some changes in the cassandra.yaml file.

var PlainTextAuthProvider = cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider;
var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints:['myserver:9042'], 
                                    authProvider: new PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra')};

Comment: make sure that your cassandra node does listen on interface, not only on localhost

Comment: how can i do that. do i need to make changes in cassandra.yaml. and if yes then what changes should i do.

Comment: Check listen_address and listen_interface in your cassandra.yaml file.

Comment: i have set the listen_address with the same ip as i am passing in contactPoints. But still it is refusing connection.

Comment: Can you ping that ip and telnet on that ip and port 9042?

Comment: can you tell me let me know, that which cassandra-driver should i use to connect with my datastax and also this cassandra.yaml file should be present on both server or only on the server where my datastax is installed. 
Also how will the changes in cassandra.yaml reflect.... do i need to restart something.

Comment: I think this should be as a separate thread. If you want to get a proper answer you should give some more details on your environment on a concise manner.